# Unhandled exception in 0x7A47E727

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unhandled-exception

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //system("cls");
    const int x = 30;
    const int y = 15;
    string tabella[y][x];
    char bordo = '#';
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        tabella[0][i] = bordo;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        tabella[i][0] = bordo;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            std::cout << tabella[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

I don't why it gaves me this problem:

> Eccezione non gestita in 0x7A47E727 (ucrtbased.dll) in Prova1.exe: 0xC0000005: violazione di accesso durante la lettura del percorso 0xCCCCCCCC.

Here it is translated in English:

> Unhandled exception in 0x7A47E727 (ucrtbased.dll) in Test1.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation while reading path 0xCCCCCCCC.

The problem seems to be in this line:
`std::cout << tabella[i][j];`

I don't know but it started when I used the x e y variables. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 btw.

Comment: `0xCCCCCCCC` means uninitialized stack memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the array

```
const int x = 30;
const int y = 15;
string tabella[y][x];
```

but here you use the indices wrong:

```
std::cout << tabella[i][j];
```

because `i` counts from 0 to 29 and `j` counts from 0 to 14.

So you have to use:

```
std::cout << tabella[j][i];
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Look at your array bounds. You have `i` and `j` the wrong way round.

```
std::cout << tabella[i][j];
```

should be

```
std::cout << tabella[j][i];
```

Or maybe you have `x` and `y` the wrong way round in the first place.

Comment: Your last suggestion breaks other parts of the code, however

Comment: @Ctx Yes, I meant in general terms, it's pretty counter intuitive to declare an array `a[y][x]` and clearly the OP has confused himself.